# how to decrease the width of parent div and child div at the same time in html5?

Tags: html, css

I need to decrease the parent div width size. i do that, but inside of the inner div's(child) are not decrease their size automatically. its hold their places. how to decrease the child div's, parent div same time.

Comment: A demo of your problem would help

Comment: Setting the width of the child as a percentage of the parent usually works. Supply a demo for your problem on jsfiddle or post the significant bits of your HTML DOM.

Comment: If you are ok with jquery then try using offset

Answer (score 1):

"Setting the width of the child as a percentage of the parent usually works" @Aaron Digulla

http://jsfiddle.net/YswCH/

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</div>
</div>

#parent {
    background: yellow;
    width: 15em; height: 5em;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#parent:hover {
    background: yellow;
    width: 10em; height: 5em;
}
#child {
    background: red;
    width: 80%; height: 4em;
}
```